# How do I use returning into clause in Oracle sql such that I can reuse the returning value to find a previous row?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a schema that looks something like this:

```
|ID | Date_of_transaction | Special_format_of_date_as_text | Data |
```

I ran across this piece of code where I update an existing row using a statement of the format:

```
UPDATE Data 
WHERE Date_of_transaction = TRUNC(SPECIFICED_DATE) 
returning special_format_of_date_as_text into date
```

BUT what I actually want is the previous week's special_format_of_date_as_text because the report title should reflect the previous week's activity and not the current week which has not happened yet.

My question is how do I do that? I was trying to do an sub query for the returning clause using "select special_format_of_date_as_text from table where Date_of_transaction = Date_of_transaction - 7" but that didn't seem to work.

My alternative would be to just return the date as is then create another query to get the previous date using a similar query I stated directly above.

Example:

```
|ID | Date_of_transaction | Special_format_of_date_as_text | Data | Is_Updated |
|1| 28-Aug-2020 | 2020Aug28DeltaAlpha | 23.42| Y |
|2| 21-Aug-2020 | 2020Aug21DeltaAlpha | 0| N |
|3| 14-Aug-2020 | 2020Aug14DeltaAlpha | 0| N |
|4| 7-Aug-2020 | 2020Aug07DeltaAlpha | 0| N |
```

And I want to update row 2, but what I want to return is 2020Aug14DeltaAlpha because that's the week the report actually reflects and that's the title I will use for naming my report.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you, you need to make the returned expression a `scalar sub query`

```
UPDATE Data 
   SET ....
 WHERE Date_of_transaction = TRUNC(SPECIFICED_DATE) 
RETURNING (select special_format_of_date_as_text from table where Date_of_transaction = Date_of_transaction - 7) into date;
```

Comment: From what i'm reading here: [http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_scalar_subqueries2.htm] we can't add scalar sub queries to returning clauses. I tested it out as well and it returned a null.

Comment: Please check this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d276fb63cf3e42e6fe096c0b7597bd0

Comment: @Yonhas Very Nice!!! Would you mind accept the answer and give it a tick ? Thank you.